# Script fails if variable is equal to 3 only

Tags: php

I have some PHP code that does actully work absoltely fine as long as my variable $pid is equal to 1, 2 or 4. But when i run this code with $pid set to 3 the query to sent some data to a database fails. This is inside the error log: 
`Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/sndmipat/public_html/user-panel/industrihandel/upload.php:2) in /home/sndmipat/public_html/user-panel/industrihandel/upload.php on line 24`

PHP CODE:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['subup'])) {
    $data = $_POST['textbox'];
    $pid = $_GET['pid'];

    include '../../connection.php';

    $sql = "UPDATE Industrihandel SET Content='$data' WHERE ID=$pid";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if($result) {
        switch ($pid) {
        case 1:
            header("Refresh:0;url=index.php?pid=1");
            exit;
        case 2:
            header("Refresh:0;url=omraden.php?pid=2");
            exit;
        case 3:
            header("Refresh:0;url=sortiment.php?pid=3");
            exit;
        case 4:
            header("Refresh:0;url=kontakt.php?pid=4");
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        echo 'ERROR';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Permission denied.';
    echo "<br>Error message = " . mysqli_error(); //Returns: "Error message = " without any error.
}
?>
```

So when i try to run this with $pid = 3 i get "ERROR" echoed out.
Can someone please help me with this problem!
Thank you!

And i do actully have a database record with ID 3. 
https://gyazo.com/509bed3b9dde9dfed6802ab9908d81b6

Comment: maybe there is simply no record with ID=3 in your db table?

Comment: You'd only get the "ERROR" if you had an error in your query.  Does a row with ID 3 exist in your database?  You really should be retrieving, or logging, the mysql error message.

Comment: Obligatory SQL Injection Notice, never use user input directly in a query.  https://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: _sidenote:_ `if (isset($_POST['subup']))` isn't the strongest security check I can think of.

Comment: Yes, a row with ID of 3 does exist in my db.

Comment: then check for mysqli::error (as Devon has stated)! (is the place where you echo "Error" would be fitting)

Comment: you are also sure the db table is really called "Industrihandel" - without the missing "e"?

Comment: I echoed out echo "Error message = " . mysqli_error(); under echo 'ERROR';

Comment: And get a result of: Error message =

Comment: @Jeff It works when $pid is set to another number, so yes the db is called "Industrihandel".

Comment: are you willing to share the error message with us?

Comment: Also, you don't want `break` just `exit` in all cases.

Comment: I dont get any error it returns: Error message =

Comment: Ok , Thank you @AbraCadaver! I'll change that.

Comment: you are posting raw html (without preparing/binding). Is there a `'` in that html maybe? Have you switched off error_reporting maybe?

Comment: _"Thank you, the $data string was the problem!"_ -> use prepared statements then! Using them this wouldn't have been a problem!

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_query() will return **false** if the query isn't successful, so that means there's either no database record for $pid or there's an issue with the $data string format.

```
$pid = 3;
$sql = "UPDATE Industrihandel SET Content='$data' WHERE ID = $pid";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result) { // $result === false if no record exists with an ID of 3
    // ...
} else {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: As you can see here i actully have a record of 3. https://gyazo.com/509bed3b9dde9dfed6802ab9908d81b6

Comment: Thank you, the $data string was the problem!

Comment: Make sure to also validate $pid as an integer and sanitize $data to prevent SQL injection from user input.